# How to get customer that birthday date is now in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

I need to send an email to the customer that birthday date is current date, currently I've been doing like this, but no luck:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
    ...
}

public function process(){
     $collections = $this->_customerCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('birthdate',date('m-d));
}
```

Comment: have you create new customer birthdate attribute?

Comment: i use the default customer birthdate attribute @Devidas

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    private $_customerCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
    }


    public function getProcess() 
    {
        try{
            $collections = $this->_customerCollectionFactory->create();
            $collections->addAttributeToSelect('dob', date('Y-m-d'));
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }

      return $collections;

    }
```

In template

```
var_dump($block->getProcess()->getData());
```